# Localizing my iphone app, not using the localized files correctly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization, plist, xib

I am trying to localize my app. I have added locale "sv" (Swedish). I have localized both my xib file and a plist with some information I need.

When setting the simulator to English, it is using the English xib. Also, when setting the simulator to Swedish (both language and region) it still use the default English xib.

For the plist it is the opposite around. It always uses the sv-version no matter if I use English or Swedish settings.

I always change both the language and region.

I assume that I don't have to do anything special in the code, the app should just pick the correct file based on the settings on the phone, right?

I don't know how to debug from here, or fix the problem. Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean All Targets... I wanted to do this but it was always disabled. But since I'm such a newbie I didn't think about that you can only clean target when the app is not running in the simulator. But cleaning the targets made it work.

Resetting the content of the app was not sufficient but I do need to both cleant targets and reset simulator in order to get it to work.

I would be most happy to have it comfirmed that this is something that's supposed to be needed or if there's something with my application/xCode that isn't working corretly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you did something wrong with your project configuration - you are using the proper language code.

I can only assume that you have a folder `sv.lproj` in your project directory, one that contains localized versions of the files from `en.lproj`.

I recommend you to create a new application and add just the localized plist to it and check if it works. Probably it will work and you'll be able to sync project config or just move the code from the old one to the new one.

Comment: Actually, I have the English.lproj not the en.lproj. Could that be the problem? Can I just rename English.lproj to en.lproj or will I corrup something if I do that? I also have se.lproj as a remaining directory after I used the incorrect locale for Sweden. I did delete this locale but he directory still remains. Guess it shouldn't be a problem, but one never knows with xCode...

Comment: It's not possible to change the name of the English directory, if I do then the link is broken to those files.

Comment: You should investigate the Swedish directory issue, for english it doesn't matter. English, German, French and Spanish are the only languages that **can** have longer names.

Comment: I did that. No success... I added all files and then I localized some files (plist and xib), only default english is used now. I tried german (de) as well, no success... I assume it should be possible localizing the plist file?